# pouchdb: replicate from geocouch within bounds

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, geocouch

When replicating from couchDB(with geocouch), is there a way to sync documents within a bbox (bounds) ?

I'm displaying markers on a map, and I'd like to only replicate documents within the bounds of that map.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because the underlying documents are the same. When you query for a bounding box the result set should contain a list of document ids. The replicator api in couchdb can accept a list of [document ids that have to be replicated](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#One-shot_Replication). So all you have got to do is query for the bbox to get a list of _ids and pass that list to the couchdb replicator to replicate them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what I have to do is: 1. Make a GET `?bbox=` request to geocouch and extract `docIds` from the response 2. `PouchDB.replicate('mydb', 'http://localhost:5984/mydb', {doc_ids: docIds})` Also, when map's bounds change: I cancel replication and repeat the previous process -- do you agree and do you see anything else? Thank you

Comment: Yes. I answered this question assuming that you are replicating with couchdb api... I am not familiar with pouchdb's replication api but a quick google search shows me that should work.

Comment: What about new created documents ? If I use your technique (ie: listening on specific ids) I won't benefit from live pouchdb replicate feature... do you see another option ?